# Create hash map with parameters ordered in the way inserted

Tags: c++, hashmap, hash-function

I want to change the std::map (it's hash function) so when iterated to return pairs in the way they are inserted. I have tried with unordered map, but with no success. So I guess I have to create a hash function that is incrementing and returns bigger value every time. How can I do that? I'm not working with big data, so performance is not a problem.

Comment: That sounds like it would defeat the purpose of the hash map. Why not use a list or vector of pairs instead ?

Comment: _hash function that is incrementing and returns bigger value every time_ that's not a hash function. How would you find anything in the map?

Comment: @manni66 By index or iterating through it of course, same as for `std::vector`.

Comment: @Caninonos It doesn't, you want O(1) lookups but iteration based on insertion order. This is a common idiom in Python, but you can do it with a linked list and hashmap, although there are more efficient implementations.

Comment: if "Performance is not a problem" it sounds like the vector is by far the simplest answer

Comment: I need it as a map so I can easily access elements inside. Instead of looping through entire vector I want to access the element by it's key. It will be cleaner.

Comment: You can always write a helper method for `auto it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), key);`, however, that would get glacially slow quick. Use a an existing solution: this is a known use-case for a hashmap, and numerous implementations exist.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what the purpose of a `std::map` is. If order is important, then you probably want a `std::vector`, `std::deque` or a queue. A custom hashing function which is incrementing is a possibility, if and only if it doesn't create collisions or duplicates. Another solution would be to use an `std::map` of pointers, where the key indexes the pointer, and then a vector/deque which indexes the order of insertion.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you want an ordered map, a hashmap which allows O(1) lookups but remembers the order of insertion (for iteration order). Luckily, an efficient implementation exists in C++:
https://github.com/Tessil/ordered-map

An example from the README is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tsl/ordered_map.h>

int main() 
{
    tsl::ordered_map<char, int> map = {{'d', 1}, {'a', 2}, {'g', 3}};
    map.insert({'b', 4});
    map['h'] = 5;
    map['e'] = 6;

    map.erase('a');


    // {d, 1} {g, 3} {b, 4} {h, 5} {e, 6}
    for(const auto& key_value : map) {
        std::cout << "{" << key_value.first << ", " << key_value.second << "}" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You may also implement it like Python's ordered map, which uses a linked list to track insertion order. An advantage is more efficient deletions (Tessil's ordered-map has `O(n)` deletions, while a linked list/map would be average `O(1)`). Assuming the map would normally store a key/value type of type `Key, T`, you would store `T` in the linked list, and store an iterator as the internal unordered_map's value type. You would then wrap the class and any iterators to ensure it acts from the outside like a normal hashmap.

The basic outline would look something like the following (the rest is for you to implement, if `O(n)` deletions are unacceptable). Lists are used since they do not invalidate iterators when an element is removed, and the map is used to find the correct list iterator for deletions by key. Satisfies all the big O issues, albeit with some overhead.

```
#include <list>
#include <unordered_map>

template <
    typename Key,
    typename T,
    typename Hash = std::hash<Key>,
    typename KeyEqual = std::equal_to<Key>,
    typename Allocator = allocator<std::pair<Key, T>>
>
class ordered_map
{
public:
    using key_type = Key;
    using mapped_type = T;
    // ....

private:
    using list_type = list<T, typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::template rebind_alloc<T>>;
    using list_iterator = typename list_type::iterator;
    using map_type = std::unordered_map<
        Key, list_iterator, Hasah, KeyEqual, 
        typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::template rebind_alloc<std::pair<Key, list_iterator>>
    >;

    list_type list_;
    map_type map_;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use:

`std::vector<std::pair<key,value> myValues`.

For insertion you would use code like this

`myValues.emplace_back(std::make_pair<key,value>(someKey, someValue));`

Preferably you will do this in a loop. Then when you want to get items in order they were inserted you simply loop on index For example using for-ranged based loop to output elements in order they were insterted:

`for(auto & pair : myValues)
{
    std::cout << "Key: " << pair.first << " Value: " << pair.second << std::endl;
}`

Doing this on unordered_map or regular map container would be bad use case for such container.

Comment: This does not allow efficient lookups for items in the map. Ordered hashmaps that remember the order of insertion are not new: they are actually extremely common in Python (they are currently the default hashmap implementation in Python). Considering the massive practicality one of the most popular programming languages found for an ordered hashmap (remembering insertion order), I strongly disagree that this would be a bad use-case for such a container.

Comment: I only said that it would be bad use case for unordered map or regular map from c++ STL library :)

Comment: Maybe not using a custom hash function. But you can actually wrap a standard hashmap and a linked list to create an ordered map quite efficiently. This is actually exactly what CPython does. I'm never going to downvote, but it's fairly easy to extend a standard hashmap to one that remembers insertion order.

Comment: Yeah ok, I agree. The thing is that it depends what does one want to do. If the only thing you want is to iterate in insertion order (I though that was the case) it is better to use std::vector.